# How to open cf command line interface in window

Tags: github, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I have installed CF version v6.12.2 , I have installed both Installer and Binaries. It is installed in CloudFoundry directory inside program files, but there is only binary file. I have downloaded and extracted Starter code also. How can i open cf command line interface.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Windows? To launch Command Prompt select Start -> Run and type `cmd` in the box.

Then, try typing `cf`. If that does not work, navigate to where the binary is installed, and try `cf` again.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **cf6** instead of **cf**.

I installed CF 7 and it has a cf7.exe in the installation folder, so in this case I have to use **cf7** instead of **cf** command.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, it was installed on "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Cloud Foundry"

After installed the CLI , you hit windows logo key + R , then "CMD"

a black console will pop up , then try run "**cf**" , if does not work , then try "**cf7**".....

Answer (score 0):

For me, cf worked within the installation folder but I needed it to execute within a project folder..

After running **CMD in Admin mode**, rather than cf I used my current version being **cf8** which worked.